# How to take snapshots of a RDS database and store it in S3 automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I have an RDS postgres database in aws and I need to automatically take snapshot of the db and store the snapshot in S3.

First I tried to create a python script which will run `psql dump` command and create a dump file and then upload the dump file to s3 using `boto3` client.

This script is working fine on my machine since I have `psql` installed.

**But I need to run this script automatically everyday at particular time**

So I decided to put the script on AWS lambda but it won't work as I'm need `psql` to run the script on AWS lambda.

I'm stuck here. I looked into lot of articles and aws documentation but I can't find the exact solution that I need.

I need to automatically take snapshot of an RDS db and upload the backup to S3 everyday at particular time.

What will be the suitable solution for this case?

Comment: I would suggest using a Lambda Container Image for this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html You could then have your Dockerfile install `psql` for the image that you create and upload to ECR

Comment: Have you considered simply using the Amazon RDS snapshot capability instead of storing your own `pg_dump` backups?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Can we automate the process of taking Amazon RDS snapshots?

Comment: Yes. Amazon RDS can perform **automatic snapshots** on a continual basis that can be kept for up to 35 days. You can also create **manual snapshots** at any time via an API call or [by using AWS Backup](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-mysql-automated-backups/). Amazon RDS snapshots can be restored as a **new database** without impacting your existing database. The whole process is managed by Amazon RDS. No need to use pg_dump files and manage their storage.